# Call this (public) function inside private function

Tags: javascript

I have the following javascript: ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mansfield/7XEYD/2/))

```
$(function () {
    function Cat()
    {  
        this.Meow = function (sound) {
            alert("Meow: " + sound);
        }

        this.Kick = function () {
            MakeNoise();    
        }

        var MakeNoise = function () {
            Meow("noise");
            //Cat.Meow("noise");
            //self.Meow("noise");
            //this.Meow("noise");                      
        }        
    }

    var c = new Cat();
    c.Kick();
});​
```

When I call the `Kick` function, I get the error "Meow is not defined" (with any of the four things I tried in the `MakeNoise` function).

I also tried prototyping like so but that gave me the same error:

```
Cat.prototype.Meow = function (sound) {
    return this.Meow(sound);    
}
```

I've sure this has a terribly straightforward solution, but I can't figure out how to successfully call the `Meow` function of the "Cat" class. How can I do this?

As an aside, does this architecture make any sense at all? My intention was to have `Kick` and `Meow` as public functions, and `MakeNoise` as private.

Comment: Musa's answer below will do the trick, but I'd encourage you to take a look at the following article for more explanation about 'this' and scoping. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this

Comment: @gerges Thanks for the link. I assumed (incorrectly it seems) that this would refer to the current object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save a reference object so you can use it in the `MakeNoise` function.

```
$(function () {
    function Cat()
    {  
        var self = this;
        this.Meow = function (sound) {
            alert("Meow: " + sound);
        }

        this.Kick = function () {
            MakeNoise();    
        }

        var MakeNoise = function () {
            //Meow("noise");
            //Cat.Meow("noise");
            self.Meow("noise");
            //this.Meow("noise");                      
        }        
    }

    var c = new Cat();
    c.Kick();
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/7XEYD/3/